# SSRS hybrid action Go to URL go to report

Tags: recursion, reporting-services, action

I'm developing a recoursive bar chart with the capability to navigate through a tree hierarchy by getting parent and child data from stored procedures.

It works well but I need to define a different action for the last node that instead of `go to report` should be: `go to URL`.

[ssrs Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekYEv.png)

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved by using **go to url for both**: go to report and go to url.

this is possible by specifying the Url of the report as go to url concatenating the parameters using the HTTG GET syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As you cannot set the report action via an expression, the easiest way I can think of doing this is to have two copies of your control or whatever you need the the action on. Have one point to your report as normal and one that points to your URL. Then set the visibility of each control based on the node.

So, assuming it's the series property that you have the action on...normally the Goto report series would be visible but when you are at the last node, the goto URL series would be visible.

This should work but I've not tested it.

Alternatively, if you can determine if the next node will be the last one, you could have two copies of the report. The first would be your report as it is now and the seconds would be exactly the same but with as different action. You can set an expression to call the correct report in the goto report action properties based on the node level. As I said before though, you will need to know if the node you are looking at is the penultimate one.

Neither solution is that elegant but it should give you what you want,.